# Rails 3 - Request Params turn into Scope calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, controller, scope

I'm building an application that has a bunch of Monthly Total reports.  Most of them are very similar and they are all working now but the code sucks.  I have to clean this up and trying to figure out the best approach in doing so.

```
def active_monthly_total_by_type
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {
        @results = @current_account.items.totals_by_month(params[:selected_year], :status_change_date).with_type.active
        render :json => @results.collect{ |result| { :type => result.type, :jan => result.jan, :feb => result.feb, :mar => result.mar, :apr => result.apr, :may => result.may, :jun => result.jun, :jul => result.jul, :aug => result.aug, :sep => result.sep, :oct => result.oct, :nov => result.nov, :dec => result.dec } }
      }
    end
  end

  def active_monthly_total
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {
        @results = @current_account.items.totals_by_month(params[:selected_year], :status_change_date).active
        render :json => @results.collect{ |result| { :jan => result.jan, :feb => result.feb, :mar => result.mar, :apr => result.apr, :may => result.may, :jun => result.jun, :jul => result.jul, :aug => result.aug, :sep => result.sep, :oct => result.oct, :nov => result.nov, :dec => result.dec } }
      }
```

I have 6 total methods like this and I'm trying to figure out if I pass it a param of active or inactive

```
params[:active]
```

if I can attach it to this call

```
@results = @current_account.items.totals_by_month(params[:selected_year], :status_change_date).params[:active]
```

if anyone can help or give me some advise where I can look for information I would love to have one method that controls all of these calls since they are the same.  Here is the model scope:

```
def self.totals_by_month(year, date_type)
    start_date = year.blank? ? Date.today.beginning_of_year : Date.parse("#{year}0101").beginning_of_year
    end_date = year.blank? ? Date.today.end_of_year : Date.parse("#{year}0101").end_of_year
    composed_scope = self.scoped

    start_date.month.upto(end_date.month) do |month|
      composed_scope = composed_scope.select("COUNT(CASE WHEN items.#{date_type.to_s} BETWEEN '#{start_date.beginning_of_month}' AND '#{start_date.end_of_month}' THEN 1 END) AS #{Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[month].downcase}")
      start_date = start_date.next_month
    end

    composed_scope
end
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem.

Comment: Eugen, Thank you for the suggestion.  I might try that but was more interested in the way to possibly do this myself (kind of a learning experience).  I know there are things like constantize and klass etc.  I would like to see if these would work like a scopify or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a unique way to do this.  I created a method called pie_chart and bar_chart which handles HTML and JSON for the requests and implemented this structure

```
/reports/:method/:year/:name/

send(params[:method],@current_account.items.send(params[:scope], params[:year]))
```

Where the URL would be /reports/pie_chart/2010/count_types_by_year

I have a pie_chart method in my controller and a count_types_by_year as the scope in my model and works like a charm  Completely makes it dynamic and also makes it flexible for new additions...DRY baby DRY